# Can you mount a location in Linux as a symbol (ie. !)

Tags: 16.04

I have a VERY weird way that I like to manage my servers log files. I like to use a terminal with the "Cat" command to watch my server by scrolling through Server log dumps.

My question Is can I mount a Symbol like ! as a directory.

I know you can do `cd ~` to make the terminal work in `/home/USER/`

is there a way that I can do `cd !` in order to access a directory like `/Home/USER/SERVER/#/Dump` instead of doing `cd /home/USER/SERVER/#/Dump` or doing `cd ~/SERVER/#/Dump`

Thanks for reading !

Comment: You could make a symlink to that location with a one-letter name in the root directory, like `/a`. That would be an easy way to get short names, but I doubt you can assign paths to symbols, especially not to reserved symbols like `!`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use an alias for that task. Aliases are stored in the .bashrc file in your home directory. With the command

```
echo "alias cdump='cd /home/USER/SERVER/#/Dump'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

you can add an alias to your .bashrc. You can then change the working directory to the desired with just typing `cdump`in the terminal. But you need to restart the terminal in order to make the changes usable.

And be careful to use `>>` since a single `>` would override your whole .bashrc!!

Comment: You could further this by using GNU `screen` or `tmux` to create a 'session' of all your logs.  You can also look into `rsyslog` to consolidate logs across multiple machines. :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can mount a filesystem to any legal directory name, including directories whose names are a single symbol.  However, specifying symbols as filenames can be clunky using most shells, since you have to escape them with a backslash.  To answer the specific question asked, to mount to a !, for example:

```
$ cd /
$ sudo mkdir \!
$ sudo mount -t proc proc ./\!
```

The above makes the directory /! another proc filesystem on your computer.  You would need to escape the symbol again when you refer to it by doing

```
$ cd /\!
```

You need to escape the symbols ***! # &*** in the above manner.  You do not need to escape the symbols ***^ , @ $ %*** but I would be careful using some of them.

You cannot change directories to it directly, though, like you can with cd ~ to do directly to your home directory.  The ~ symbol is a shortcut in the shell, not something special in OS. Even if you put the directory off your root directory, you still need to use the / to get to it from anywhere, as in:

```
$ cd /^
```

To do what you really want there is one way, but then you lose the ability to access your home directory quickly.  You can use the ~ symbol. If I do this:

```
$ mkdir /some/path/to/mountpoint
$ mount something /some/path/to/mountpoint
$ export HOME=/some/path/to/mountpoint
```

then if I use "cd ~" it will take me to the mountpoint instead of my home directory.  You would need to be careful doing this, though, as certain scripts may depend on ~ referring to your actual home directory.

Answer (score 0):

My preference (it's all individual in this world) would be to edit `~/.bashrc` and manually add these lines:

```
# change directory aliases, cdd for AU question
alias cdd='cd /home/'$USER'/SERVER/#/Dump'
alias cdh='cd /home/'$USER
alias cdm='cd /media/'$USER'/ST9_Win7/Users/Person/Music/iTunes/'"iTunes Media"'/Music'
```

- The first alias is for your question--`cdd` = change directory dump.
- The second alias is handy for everyone--`cdh` = change directory / home / user. Tilde (`~`) is so hard to type for me.
- The last alias is for myself--`cdm` = change to music directory. Music is stored on a Windows partition and nested so deeply it's painful navigating there.

Later on I'll add more cd aliases. For example, `cd /var/log` would be abbreviated to the alias`cdv`.

I enjoy questions like yours that lead to answers I get to use myself. Thank you :)